# angular two validations fire in the same time

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

I validate my angular form using below code

```
       <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" minlength="12" maxlength="12" name="accountno" #accountNo="ngModel" required class="form-control"  pattern="^[0-9]*$"
                [(ngModel)]="registerUser.accountNo"    [class.is-invalid]="accountNo.invalid && accountNo.touched"
                placeholder="Account No.">
                <div [class.d-none]="accountNo.valid || accountNo.untouched">
                    <small *ngIf="accountNo.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Account No. is required</small>
                    <small *ngIf="accountNo.hasError('pattern')" class="text-danger">Accout No. should be 12 numbers</small>
                    <small *ngIf="accountNo.hasError('minlength')" class="text-danger">Accout No. must be at least 12 Numbers.</small>
                </div>
            
            </div>
```

When I typing letters in the textbox, two validations fire in same time. please check below image

[image]

how i load my validations one by one.. thanks

Comment: You could either display both messages simultaneously (below each other, perhaps) or you could adapt the condition of one error to not be displayed if the other is visible.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behavior, since the text you provided is not a valid number and it has less than 12 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NgSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) instead of ngIf and some function call that returns the first key of formControl.errors object I think it can help